# Problem with Convert.ToInt32 and getting error Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, linq, checksum, crc

We want get crc code from a string.
for example: string is (ff03c1) and crc code is (3d).

The bellow code works correctly until the string is less than 186 characters.
sample string:

```
20000F38080000D1080020110800190D0000000000000000000000000000000020000F38080000D1080020110800190D000000000000000000000000000000020000F38080000D1080020110800190D000000000000000000000000000
```

But this string not working (187 characters):

```
20000F38080000D1080020110800190D0000000000000000000000000000000020000F38080000D1080020110800190D000000000000000000000000000000020000F38080000D1080020110800190D000000000000000000000000000**0**
```

error: 
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length

```
public static string CreateCRCCode(string Value)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, Value.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(Value.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .Aggregate((i, i1) => i ^ i1)
                     .ToString("X");
}
```

how we can use string more than 186 character?

Comment: This code will fail for any string with odd length, because of `Value.Substring(x, 2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Root cause**

The real problem is not with the `186` or `187` characters, the problem is the `odd` and `even`, what I tried to say is, you will get the same error for an input of `200` as well. The reason is that,

- Consider that the Value = "200" so,  `Value.Length = 3` and hence `Enumerable.Range(0, Value.Length)` will gives you `0,1,2`.
- After applying `.Where(x => x % 2 == 0)` the collection became `0,2`.
- So when applying the [substring](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-substring-method/)(`Value.Substring(x, 2)`) it will search for the substring starts at index `2` and off length `2`(in the second iteration) which is not a valid index. That causes the error.

**Proposed Fix**:

- I don't get any reason for applying `Where(x => x % 2 == 0)` in the given snippet, if it is necessary please cross check the conditions and scenarios.
- Change the `Enumerable.Range` based on the collection length like the following:

  ```
  Enumerable.Range(0, Value.Length % 2 == 0 ? Value.Length : Value.Length-1)
  ```